# Regarding linux package

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-kernel

I need to get below packages installed on Oracle Linux 6.7.
However, when installing I am getting below error.

```
[root@oraclelinux1 ~]# yum install sysstat-9.0.4-11.el6-x86_64
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security, ulninfo
Setting up Install Process
No package sysstat-9.0.4-11.el6-x86_64 available.
```

As per my knowledge, Above error says that the below packages are not available. Could any suggest how can I download these packages on Oracle Linux box as I am new to Linux.

- binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.11.el6-x86_64
- compat-libcap1-1.10-1-x86_64
- compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-x86_64
- compat-libstdc++-33-3.2.3-69.el6-i686
- libgcc-4.4.4-13.el6-i686
- libgcc-4.4.4-13.el6-x86_64
- libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6-x86_64
- libstdc++-4.4.4-13.el6-i686
- libstdc++-devel-4.4.4-13.el6-x86_64
- sysstat-9.0.4-11.el6-x86_64
- gcc-4.4.4-13.el6-x86_64
- gcc-c++-4.4.4-13.el6-x86_64
- glibc-2.12-1.7.el6-i686
- glibc-2.12-1.7.el6-x86_64
- glibc-devel-2.12-1.7.el6-x86_64
- glibc-devel-2.12-1.7.el6
- libaio-0.3.107-10.el6-x86_64
- libaio-devel-0.3.107-10.el6-x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Which repos did you have on oracle linux 6.7? Did you try # yum install sysstat? Maybe sysstat-9.0.4-11 was no longer on your repos.
You can use  # yum list > packagelist.txt to check all  packages on your repos.So you can install all packages that you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.I looked into the list of packages.However,the above packages doesnot exist.Could you please tell me how I need to download the above packages on oracle Linux box.

Comment: suggest you add output of `yum repolist` and `yum search sysstat` to your question

Comment: Actually all packages should be on Oracle linux 6.7 dvd/cd or Centos 6.7 dvd/cd too.Oracle linux 6.7 based on centos/RHEL 6.7.Oracle linux 6.7 customized by Oracle for oracle database.

Comment: I have checked the output the repolist and found that some of the above packages not present.Could you please tell procedure to download the packages which are not present from online.

Comment: Which repos did you have ?Check on /etc/yum.repos.d/... Did you have EPEL repos?

Comment: Seems like EPEL repos doesnot exist. Could you please tell how to add the same.

Comment: You can download rpm packages here : rpm.pbone.net and search for epel or another repos